# Trying to implement a 5 function calculator in javascript using event listener

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JS Operator</title>

    <script>
        function calculate(num1, num2, op){
            switch (op){
                case '+' : return num1 + num2

                case '-' : return num1 - num2

                case '*' : return num1 * num2

                case '/' : return num1 / num2

                case '%' : return num1 % num2
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input id="num1" type="number" placeholder="Enter first number" name="num1"/> <br/><br/>
    <input id="num2" type="number" placeholder="Enter second number" name="num2"/> <br/><br/>
    <input id="op" type="text" placeholder="Enter operator" name="op"/> <br/><br/>

    <button id="calculate" name="calculate"> Calculate </button><br/>

    <p id="result">Result: </p>

    <script>
        var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
        var op = document.getElementById("op").value;

        document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: "
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+= calculate(num1, num2, op)
        })

    </script>
</body>
```

This is the code i've written, not sure where it is going wrong, but upon hitting the calculate button, the result reads undefined. I also tried using parseInt() for the 2 numeric values but that didn't work, although when i try to print the values of the 3 vars using alert() it gives the same value as input. Please help someone to get through where the error is.

Comment: Why do you not place all your code inside the event handler?

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two (common!) issues:

1. Please put the `.value()` calls inside the event listener!
2. Wrap the `.value()` calls in `Number(...)` so that addition is numeric addition and not string concatenation.

Here's one possible look for your script at the bottom portion of your code:

```
const num1Box = document.getElementById("num1");
const num2Box = document.getElementById("num2");
const opBox = document.getElementById("op");
const resultArea = document.getElementById("result");

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const x = Number(num1Box.value);
  const y = Number(num2Box.value);
  const op = opBox.value;
  resultArea.innerHTML = `Result: ${calculate(x, y, op)}`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ray, the posted solution is clean and clear have a look at it, apart from that the working example of your code is,

```js
  document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function() {

   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Result: ";
   var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
   var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
   var op = document.getElementById("op").value;
   console.log(num1, num2);
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += calculate(num1, num2, op)
  })

  function calculate(num1, num2, op) {

   switch (op) {
    case '+':
     return num1 + num2

    case '-':
     return num1 - num2

    case '*':
     return num1 * num2

    case '/':
     return num1 / num2

    case '%':
     return num1 % num2
   }
  }
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JS Operator</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input id="num1" type="number" placeholder="Enter first number" name="num1"/> <br/><br/>
      <input id="num2" type="number" placeholder="Enter second number" name="num2"/> <br/><br/>
      <input id="op" type="text" placeholder="Enter operator" name="op"/> <br/><br/>
      <button id="calculate" name="calculate"> Calculate </button><br/>
      <p id="result">Result: </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried out the following code after posting the question, was engaged so couldn't update. Below it is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JS Operator</title>

        <script>
            function calculate(){

                var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
                var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
                var op = document.getElementById("op").value;
                var result = 0;

                switch (op){
                    case '+' : result = num1 + num2;
                            break;

                    case '-' : result =  num1 - num2;
                            break;

                    case '*' : result =  num1 * num2;
                            break;

                    case '/' : result =  num1 / num2;
                            break;

                    case '%' : result =  num1 % num2;
                            break;
                }
                document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "Result: ";
                document.getElementById("res").innerHTML += result;

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input id="num1" type="number" placeholder="Enter first number"/> <br/><br/>
        <input id="num2" type="number" placeholder="Enter second number"/> <br/><br/>
        <input id="op" type="text" placeholder="Enter operator"/> <br/><br/>

        <button id="calc"> Calculate </button><br/>

        <script>
            document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", function(){calculate()})
        </script>

        <p id="res">Result: </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is fine, but a couple tips: (1) Avoid the horrible `parseInt` because it accepts values like `"39xufew`, and it incorrectly interprets `"2e3"` as `2` instead of `2000`, and (2) instead of `function(){calculate()}`, just write `calculate`. Glad your calculator is taking shape.